# How can I calculate the negativity?

Tags: code

I tried to calculate the negativity that is defined as follows:

$eq(1): N = Tr(Sqrt(A.A\dagger))-1$

The result should be ~0.41 in for example r~0.01 (when r is close to 0) and it decreases versus r.  The range of r is 0 to 0.8. So when r increases, the negativity should decrease. Anyway, my result is different.

Notice that first we must diagonalize the matrix p (calculating the eigenvalues). Then we take the square root of the eigenvalues. Then we need to sum the eigenvalues using the `Total` function (it's to calculate the trace of the diagonal matrix).

After that we need to do a sum from m = 0 to infinity (I know it's not part of the $eq (1)$ but we must do it. [For more info look at page 5 of the article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.6154)

Also notice that the matrix is equal to its dagger so $p = p\dagger$. So can we say based on $eq (1)$ the negativity can calculated like this below?

$eq(2):N=tr(p)-1 $

Here is my code:

```
Off[General::precw]; 
a = b = 1/Sqrt[3]; 
r = 0.01; 
Subscript[p, r] = 
  MatrixForm[{{((m*b^2)/Cosh[r]^4)*
       Tanh[r]^(2*m - 2) + (1 - a^2 - b^2)*(Tanh[r]^(2*m)/Cosh[r]^2), 
     0, 0, ((b*a)/Cosh[r]^3)*Sqrt[m + 1]*Tanh[r]^(2*m)}, 
         {0, (a^2/Cosh[r]^2)*Tanh[r]^(2*m), 0, 0}, {0, 
     0, (1 - a^2 - b^2)*(Tanh[r]^(2*m + 2)/
         Cosh[r]^2) + (((m + 1)*b^2)/Cosh[r]^4)*Tanh[r]^(2*m), 0}, 
         {((a*b)/Cosh[r]^3)*Sqrt[m + 1]*Tanh[r]^(2*m), 0, 
     0, (a^2/Cosh[r]^2)*Tanh[r]^(2*m + 2)}}]; 
Subscript[pp, r] = Subscript[p, r] . Subscript[p, r]; 
Subscript[eigen, r] = Eigenvalues[Subscript[pp, r]]; 
Subscript[seigen, r] = Sqrt[Subscript[eigen, r]]; 
Subscript[Ne, r] = 
 Re[NSum[Total[Subscript[seigen, r]], {m, 0, Infinity}]] - 1
```

Comment: Crossposted here: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2922466

Comment: `Subscript[p, r] = MatrixForm[...` This is wrong. Do not use `MatrixForm` for anything other than presentational purposes. If you use it in calculations like this, you will encounter problems.

Comment: As @flinty points out, avoid MatrixForm in assignments.  MatrixForm is a directive for rendering, not something that takes a grid of numbers and tells mathematica to treat it mathematically like a matrix.

Second, you probably want to avoid `Subscript`.  It is possible to code correctly with subscript, but it's not easy.  You can instead just do eg. `p[r]`.

Answer (score 3):

The negativity can be calculated via

```
negativity[A_] := Total[Sqrt[Eigenvalues[A . A\[ConjugateTranspose]]]] - 1
```

We can test this,

```
negativity[PauliMatrix[1]] (* gives 1*)
negativity[PauliMatrix[2]] (* gives 1*)

(* 
gives graphics showing a distribution of negativities of 1000 matrices
with entries randomly picked from [0, 1].
*)
Histogram[negativity /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1000, 100, 100}]]
```

You can use `negativity` on your matrix if you can construct it numerically.